# Does AWS support the TRIM command for EBS volumes that are SSD-backed?

Tags: ssd, amazon-web-services, trim, forensics

I've gone over [Amazon's documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ssd-instance-store.html) and it seems that the TRIM command is only implemented for some instance types that have internal SSDs (specifically, the C5d, G4, I3, I3en, F1, M5ad, M5d, p3dn.24xlarge, R5ad, R5d, and z1d types).

However, when an EC2 instance communicates with EBS devices that are SSD-backed, it doesn't seem that the TRIM command is passed over the channel (is it iSCSI?) to the remote EBS server.

Is this the case, and is there any way to activate the TRIM command on remote SSD-based EBS servers?

Comment: What problem are you having, or what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I don't have a problem. I'm doing digital forensics.  On devices that support TRIM, the OS will send a TRIM command to the device when a file is deleted, and it's progressively harder to get back deleted files as time passes. That's not the case on drives that don't support TRIM. So I'd like to know the situation with EBS. The behavior is not documented.

Comment: I doubt that level of detail has been released by AWS about EBS. You're not addressing an SSD directly, you're addressing a disk array with some unknown and possibly proprietary software in front of it.

Comment: "and it's progressively harder to get back deleted files as time passes" - In most cases *immediately* the file is unrecoverable once LBA sectors allocated to file were trimmed as most common (AFAIK) behavior is RZAT.

Comment: @JoepvanSteen — I do not think that RZAT was widely deployed in 2020 when the question was asked.

Comment: I do think it was very common. https://youtu.be/hzClnwGeJUM

Answer (score 0):

This, admittedly old, AWS blog mentions that EBS does not support the trim operation: [How to Build Sparse EBS Volumes for Fun and Easy Snapshotting](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/apn/how-to-build-sparse-ebs-volumes-for-fun-and-easy-snapshotting/)

The text says:

> While many SSD controllers support native TRIM operations, including Amazon EC2 Instance Store volumes, EBS does not.